# Как сделать фиксированную высоту ячеек таблицы?

Tags: php, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь создать чат на сервере и возникла такая проблема: при удалении строк из таблицы, размер ячеек меняется относительно самой таблицы. Как сделать фиксированный размер ячеек, чтоб при удалении других ячеек они оставались той же высоты ?

```css
 .tab2{
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 880px;
  height: 710px;      
 }
    .trMessage{
  max-height: 24px;
 }
    .message{
 width: 870px;
 height: 24px;
 padding-bottom: 4px;
 border-bottom:1px solid;
 border-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.31);
}
```

```html
 <table class="tab2">
    <?foreach ($messages as $key => $value) {?>
     <tr class="trMessage">
       <td class="message">             
         <?echo $value['date']?> <?echo $value['user']?>: <?echo $value['text']?>       
        <br />              
       </td>      
       <td>
        <?if(checkPrivilege($_SESSION['user'])){?> 
         <form method="post" class="deleteform">
          <input type="hidden" name="messageid" value="<?=$value['id']?>" />
          <input type="submit" name="delete" class="deleteButton" value="x" onclick="getValue(messageid)" />
         </form>
         <?}?>
       </td>
     </tr>
    <?}?>
   </table>
```

Comment: внутрь `td` поместить `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте убрать высоту .tab2 ( удалите height: 720px;)

Comment: Спасибо! Убрал высоту таблицы, все отлично заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать не фиксированую высоту для ячейки, а ограничить ее по высоте `.message { max-height: 15px; }`.

Comment: Случайно отправил не тот кусок кода. Высоту .message я задал, но это не помогло.

Comment: подправил ответ

Answer (score -1):

Внутри ячеек, можно расположить div и уже ему присвоить фиксированную высоту.

```
<td class="message">
  <div class="message-text">Сообщение</div>
</td>
```

---

```
.message-text {
  height: 25px;
  //overflow: hidden;
}
```